# Allow overlay scrolling behind another fixed element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Given the following structure, how can I allow scrolling the `#overlay` div when the mouse is over the fixed `#widget` div sitting on top of it -- while still allowing interaction with the widget?

Using `pointer-events: none;` on the `#widget` element solves the scrolling issue - but then no interaction with the widget is possible anymore.

It would be possible to set `pointer-events: all` on child elements of the widget (e.g. a close button), but I need the whole widget to be interactive.

I'm not looking for practical suggestions like moving the mouse off the widget but rather technical solutions to this exact problem by applying css, javascript, html attributes or by changing the structure.

```css
#parent {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
}

#parent-content {
  background: green;
}

.content {
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  bottom: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#widget {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  background: gold;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="overlay">
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div id="parent-content">
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div id="widget"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are interacting with the modal why would you need scrolling on the other content? Frankly it's a simple minor mouse move required which it a very small issue.

Comment: @Paulie_D The modal just happens to be in front of the overlay all the time even when there is no interaction with it. It’s actually more like a picture-in-picture element. So when the mouse happens to be over that element I still want to be able to scroll the overlay.

Comment: @Paulie_D I changed "modal" to "widget" because you’re right that "modal" implies that it is in front of and deactivates all other page content. Thank you.

Comment: @CBroe the widget doesn’t have scrollable content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the scroll event is sometimes difficult to monitor. Try using the `wheel` event in JavaScript.

```
$('#widget').addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
   $('#overlay').scrollBy(0,50);
});
```

*(Note: I didn't make the demo work in reverse (i.e. scrolling back up) - I leave that as an exercise to the reader.)*

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

$('#widget').addEventListener('click', () => {
   alert('hi');
});

$('#widget').addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
   $('#overlay').scrollBy(0,50);
});
```

```css
#parent {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
}

#parent-content {
  background: green;
}

.content {
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: left;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  bottom: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  color:cyan;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#widget {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  background: gold;
  z-index: 2;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="overlay">
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div id="parent-content">
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div id="widget">Scroll on Me<br>Click on Me</div>
</div>
```